# Bootstrap v3 to v5

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, migration, bootstrap-5

My team will start the POC of migration from Bootstrap v3 to v5. Firstly is that possible ? What are the different kind of roadblocks that the team might face.

Comment: Did you read https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/migration/ ?

Comment: Possible yes, difficult extremely. Consider it as almost an rewrite of most things. For starters, JQuery was dropped in v5, so most of your JS code for Bootstrap components (modals, popovers and so on), will need to be written according to the new ways.